# Can't open google compute engine's console

Tags: google-compute-engine

I tried to visit my project in google computing engine console just now :

https://cloud.google.com/console#/c=gce&pid=xxxxxxxxxx&gce=instances

and I got a very strange error message :

Server request failed: Invalid value for field 'zone': 'rtb-europe-west1-a'. Unknown zone.

what's the wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that, we had an issue with the admin console, should fixed now.  Please let me know if you continue to have an issue.

Comment: still have this issue